# Python requests to local address throws SSLError

Tags: python, ssl, ssl-certificate, python-requests

I have a python3 django website with certificate by letsencrypt

Everything is fine, except request to local address using python requests:

```
response = requests.post('http://127.0.0.1:8100', data=data)
```

And it has very strange behaviour:

Sometimes I get 200, but after `supervisorctl restart mywebsite` it throws **SSLError**

Then I made:

```
response = requests.post('http://127.0.0.1:8100', data=data, verify=True)
```

Everything is fine untill I make `supervisorctl restart mywebsite` one more time, and it throws **SSLError** O_o and now works only with

```
response = requests.post('http://127.0.0.1:8100', data=data)
```

So the final working code is:

```
try:
    response = requests.post('http://127.0.0.1:8100', data=data, verify=True)
except:
    try:
        response = requests.post('http://127.0.0.1:8100', data=data)
    except:
        response = requests.post('http://127.0.0.1:8100', data=data, verify=False)
```

And obviously this is not the best plan)

Big thx for advices

Comment: Please review my answer below, and upvote or mark as accepted if it was helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your web app is issuing a redirect from `http://` to `https://`. You could verify this by looking at the response headers with `curl -v`. After the redirect, you are probably getting the SSL error because of using localhost instead of a domain name:

> You can't get a certificate for localhost; the certificate authority is only able to issue certificates for publicly-visible, globally-unique domain names. localhost doesn't count, and the certificate authority isn't allowed to issue certs for it. --  https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/can-i-test-lets-encrypt-client-on-localhost/15627

edit:

Try doing the initial request on the `https://` URL with `verify=False`.

Comment: Hi, sory for that late response, I tried https insted http:

response = requests.post('https://127.0.0.1:8100', data=data, verify=True)

It doesnot work, very long request with timeout

Comment: Did you try my last edit suggestion?
> Try doing the initial request on the https:// URL with verify=False.